# how to exclude a property of a nested model from openaip schema in loopback 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, openapi, loopback4

I was trying to exclude the property of the nested model on the openAPI schema. Is it possible to do that in the controller with `@requestbody()` decorator?

Example

```js
@model()
export class ChildModel {
    @property()
    id: string;

    @property()
    name: string;
}

@model()
export class ParentModel {
    @property()
    description: string;

    @property()
    childModel: ChildModel;
}
```

If I used `ParentModel` in the request body I could exclude `description` or `childModel`. But I couldn't find a way to exclude `name` or `id` from `childModel`.